# How to display a list of hashmaps in ui:repeat?

Tags: jsf, facelets, el

I have a problem using JSF to display some data in Facelets. I have list of hashmaps:

```
List<Map<String, String>> persons = new LinkedList<Map<String,String>>();

public List getPersons() {
    return this.persons;
}
```

I get this as follows from database:

```
while(rs.next()) {
  Map<String,String> result = new HashMap<String,String>();
  result.put("name", rs.getString(1));
  result.put("category", rs.getString(2));
  this.persons.add(result);
}
```

So, my problem is how to display info for every map in xhtml. I try to used `ui:repeat` but it is wrong so I need help. I must have getter for name and family but how should I add it?

```
<ui:repeat value="#{class.persons}" var="persons">   
  <h:outputText value="#{persons['name'}"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{persons['family'}"/>                       
</ui:repeat>
```

I hope you understand my problem and will help me to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#{persons}` is thus a `Map<String, String>`. You can access map values by keys in the same way as normal Javabeans. So `#{person.name}` will return `map.get("name")`.

So, this should do:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{class.persons}" var="person">   
  <h:outputText value="#{person.name}"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{person.family}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

*(I only renamed `persons` to `person`, because it essentially represents only one person)*

The following way is by the way also valid and it would actually be the only way if you have a map key which contained periods:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{class.persons}" var="persons">   
  <h:outputText value="#{persons['name']}"/>
  <h:outputText value="#{persons['family']}"/>                       
</ui:repeat>
```

*(you see, you were close, you only forgot the closing brace)*

The normal practice, however, is to create a Javabean class instead of a `Map` if it actually represents an entity.

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String family;
    // ...

    // Add/generate getters/setters and other boilerplate.
}
```

And feed it as `List<Person>` to the view.